# Counting by buckets - plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

Supposedly I have the following table:

```
ID  Apple Orange Banana
1    Y     Y      N
2    N     Y      N
3    Y     N      N
4    Y     N      Y
```

How should I write the query in plsql which will give me the following?

```
ID  Apple Orange Banana
Y    3     2      1
N    1     2      3
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method using conditional aggregation:

```
select x.id,
       sum(case when apple = x.id then 1 else 0 end) as Apple,
       sum(case when orange = x.id then 1 else 0 end) as Orange,
       sum(case when banana = x.id then 1 else 0 end) as Banana
from t cross join
     (select 'Y' as id from dual union all
      select 'N' from dual
     ) x
group by x.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Y' id,
  SUM(DECODE(apple,'Y',1)) apple_cnt,
  SUM(DECODE(Orange,'Y',1)) Orange_cnt,
  SUM(DECODE(Banana,'Y',1)) Banana_cnt
FROM
  (SELECT '1' ID, 'Y' Apple, 'Y' Orange, 'N' Banana FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' , 'N', 'Y', 'N' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '3' , 'Y' , 'N' , 'N' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '4' , 'Y' , 'N' , 'Y' FROM dual
  )
UNION ALL
SELECT 'N' id,
  SUM(DECODE(apple,'N',1)) apple_cnt,
  SUM(DECODE(Orange,'N',1)) Orange_cnt,
  SUM(DECODE(Banana,'N',1)) Banana_cnt
FROM
  (SELECT '1' ID, 'Y' Apple, 'Y' Orange, 'N' Banana FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' , 'N', 'Y', 'N' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '3' , 'Y' , 'N' , 'N' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '4' , 'Y' , 'N' , 'Y' FROM dual
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If shown structure of table is not mandatory, i'd suggest you structure like this:

```
ID  FRUIT   FLAG
1   Apple   Y
2   Apple   Y
3   Apple   Y
4   Apple   N
5   Orange  N
6   Orange  N
7   Orange  N
8   Orange  Y
9   Orange  Y
10  Banana  Y
11  Banana  N
12  Banana  Y
13  Banana  Y
14  Banana  N
```

For this design, you can use [Pivot Query](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT Fruit, Flag FROM tab1) PIVOT (COUNT (Fruit)
                                      FOR (fruit)
                                      IN  ('Apple' AS Apple,
                                          'Orange' AS Orange,
                                          'Banana' AS Banana))
```

result:

```
FLAG    APPLE   ORANGE  BANANA
Y       3       2       3
N       1       3       2
```

another variant:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT Fruit, Flag FROM tab1) PIVOT (COUNT (Flag)
                                      FOR (Flag)
                                      IN ('Y' AS Yes, 'N' AS No))
```

result:

```
FRUIT   YES NO
Apple   3   1
Orange  2   3
Banana  3   2
```

Answer (score -1):

This below query works !!!.. Tried and tested.

```
select id,sum(apple),sum(orange),sum(banana) 
from
(select 'Y' ID, count(1)apple,0 orange, 0 banana  from table_name where apple ='Y'
UNION ALL
select 'Y', 0 ,count(1),0  from table_name where orange ='Y'
UNION ALL
select 'Y',0, 0,  count(1)  from table_name where banana ='Y'
UNION ALL
select 'N', count(1),0,0  from table_name where apple ='N'
UNION ALL
select 'N', 0,count(1),0  from table_name where orange ='N'
UNION ALL
select 'N', 0,0,count(1)  from table_name where banana ='N'
)
group by id;
```